# Drawing a line in a table in latex

Tags: tables

I am using LaTeX with the following code

```
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{5cm} | }
 \hline

    Parameter & Equation  \\ \hline
    Compensation \\  Capacitor & $some equation$ \\ \hline 


   \end{tabular}
```

However it seems that the table is not completely closed. How do I close only the right end of the table

[image]

Comment: Add an apersand (`&`) after the word *Compensation*.

Comment: by the way, you  are defining 4 columns, but are using only two of them. Is that on purpose?

Comment: You specified a table with 4 columns but seem not to use every one in every row. I'd suggest to be more explicit and to use `\multicolumn` when you want entries to span multiple columns.

Comment: Nope . Not on purpose. I am just getting started. I forgot to delete the unused columns. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here is an working example:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | l | p{5cm} | }
    \hline % the line at the top
    Parameter & Equation \\ \hline
    Compensation & \\ % we have an empty cell here  
    Capacitor & $some equation$ \\
    \hline % the line at the bottom
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: `$some equations$` puts text into math mode; I'd suggest to drop the `$`.